# Create Windows 7 installer ISO with preinstalled softwares?

Tags: windows-7, installation, iso-image

Is it possible to create a Windows 7 installer ISO image with software installed and configured?

For example I install a clean Windows, configure it, install some necessary software etc. and I make an installer from the current system. 
Next time I want to install Windows, just run the installer, and I have my system with the right settings, and software pre-installed and configured.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application [rt7lite](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/RT-Seven-Lite.shtml) was created specifically to allow you to create slipstream Windows 7 installs. There are other ways; MSDN has some [other recommended methods](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d9e3068a-73ed-4670-bc1e-02283cbd5f8f/windows-7-sp1-final-how-to-slipstream-with-all-builds?forum=w7itproinstall) you should probably read. Some posts in that thread argue against using rt7lite.

Answer (score -1):

You can to think about [Almeza Multiset](http://www.almeza.com/content/view/31/41/)

Answer (score -1):

I hope someone here finds it useful

http://www.howtohaven.com/system/createwindowssetupdisk.shtml

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.